# Bind values from a list array to listbox

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, listbox

Could any body give a short example for binding a value from list array to listbox in c#.net

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It depends on how your list array is.

Let's start from an easy sample:

```
List<string> listToBind = new List<string> { "AA", "BB", "CC" };
this.listBox1.DataSource = listToBind;
```

Here we have a list of strings, that will be shown as items in the listbox.

[image]

Otherwise, if your list items are more complex (e.g. custom classes) you can do in this way:

Having for example, `MyClass` defined as follows:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public MyClass(int id, string text)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.Text = text;
    }
}
```

here's the binding part:

```
List<MyClass> listToBind = new List<MyClass> { new MyClass(1, "One"), new MyClass(2, "Two") };
this.listBox1.DisplayMember = "Text";
this.listBox1.ValueMember = "Id"; // optional depending on your needs
this.listBox1.DataSource = listToBind;
```

And you will get a list box showing only the text of your items.
Setting also `ValueMember` to a specific Property of your class will make `listBox1.SelectedValue` containing the selected `Id` value instead of the whole class instance.

N.B.
Letting `DisplayMember` unset, you will get the `ToString()` result of your list entries as display text of your `ListBox` items.

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to bind, but still read back the whole class instance? Let's say I wanted to retrieve the actual text that was selected, instead of the Id (while keeping Id as the value member), could I do so?

Comment: @McAdam331: yes, just don't set anything as `ValueMember`. In this way `listBox1.SelectedValue` property will be of type `MyClass`.

Comment: Awesome! I was hoping you still used your account, I can really apply this to a project I'm working on.