# C#: Linking string[] and int[] elements to stay together when sorting int[]

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, listbox

So I need to take names and ages of people, store them in two separate arrays, sort them by age, and then display the results in a listbox. I have everything down until putting it back into the listbox. It sounds simple, but the foreach loop (from my very basic understanding of C#) can only take the values of one of the arrays. I need the names and ages on the same line because they're linked together, so I decided to switch to a for loop. However, even though my sorting on the Ages works just fine, I can't make the name match the age. Here is some of my code:

```
    const int MAX = 100;
    int count = 0;

    int[] Age = new int[MAX];
    string[] NameEntry = new string[MAX];
```

Just to show you how I declared the arrays. Here is my "store" click event:

```
    int age;

        if (txtName.Text == "")
        {
            lblWarningMessage.Text = "There is an error with your entries. A name must be entered!";
            btnClearWarn.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            NameEntry[count] = txtName.Text;

            if (int.TryParse(txtAge.Text, out age))
            {
                Age[count] = age;

                txtAge.Clear();
                txtName.Clear();
                txtName.Focus();

                lstbxResults.Items.Add(NameEntry[count] + " is " + Age[count].ToString() + " years old.");

                count++;
            }
            else
            {
                lblWarningMessage.Text = "There is an error with your entries. The Age entry must be an integer.";
                btnClearWarn.Show();
            }
        }
```

And finally, the sorting operation and subsequent for loop to add it to my listbox:

```
        Array.Resize(ref NameEntry, count);
        Array.Resize(ref Age, count);

        lstbxResults.Items.Clear();
        int minAge = 0;
        int minIndex = 0;

        for (int a = 0; a < Age.Length - 1; a++)
        {
            minAge = Age[a];
            minIndex = a;

            for (int b = a + 1; b < Age.Length; b++)
            {
                if (Age[b] < minAge)
                {
                    minAge = Age[b];
                    minIndex = b;
                }
            }

            OrderByAges(ref Age[minIndex], ref Age[a]);
        }

        for (int c = 0; c < Age.Length; c++)
        {
            lstbxResults.Items.Add(NameEntry[c] + " is " + Age[c] + " years old.");
        }
    }

    private void OrderByAges(ref int p1, ref int p2)
    {
        int temp = p2;
        p2 = p1;
        p1 = temp;
    }
```

Yes, I realize Array.sort would be faster, but this serves the same purpose, and this is how I was instructed to do it. Any thoughts on how to link the element in "NameEntry" to "Age", and have it change along with the Age when it is sorted?

Comment: Whenever you change the index of an item in Array 1 change the same index in Array 2. So if Age[2] changes to Age[5] change Name[2] to Name[5]. But it would make a LOT more sence to create a single object containing Age and Name

Comment: Maybe you should create a class to store these two (`age` and `name`) together, and get/sort array of the class instances?

Answer (score 3):

You really should use "Array.Sort" in this case. It is capable of co-sorting keys and values in two linked arrays, as in:

```
Array.Sort(Age, NameEntry, 0, count);
```

If your teacher really insists on a solution that does not use Array.Sort, just use a quicksort implementation that simply swaps the elements of both key and value at the same time:

Like this (not tested):

```
public static class CoSorter
{
    public static void Sort<TKey, TValue>(this TKey[] keys, TValue[] values, int start, int count)
    {
        QuickCosort(keys, values, start, count - 1, Comparer<TKey>.Default);
    }

    public static void Sort<TKey, TValue>(this TKey[] keys, TValue[] values, int start, int count, IComparer<TKey> comparer)
    {
        QuickCosort(keys, values, start, count - 1, comparer);
    }

    private static void QuickCosort<TKey, TValue>(TKey[] keys, TValue[] values, int left, int right, IComparer<TKey> comparer)
    {
        int i = left, j = right;
        var pivot = keys[(left + right) / 2];

        while (i <= j)
        {
            while (comparer.Compare(keys[i], pivot) < 0)
            {
                i++;
            }

            while (comparer.Compare(keys[j], pivot) > 0)
            {
                j--;
            }

            if (i <= j)
            {
                // Swap
                var tmpKey = keys[i];
                var tmpVal = values[i];
                keys[i] = keys[j];
                values[i] = values[j];
                keys[j] = tmpKey;
                values[j] = tmpVal;

                i++;
                j--;
            }
        }

        // Recursive calls
        if (left < j)
        {
            QuickCosort(keys, values, left, j, comparer);
        }

        if (i < right)
        {
            QuickCosort(keys, values, i, right, comparer);
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively you may want to think about this a bit harder and see if maybe you need a data structure instead of two arrays of values that belong together.

Comment: That works like a charm, but I was specifically instructed NOT to use Array.Sort. Is there any way to do this otherwise, or does my teacher have me running down a road to nowhere?

Comment: @user3034550 lol, you did not mention this was your homework. Well, let's help you out. I will add a co-sort routine to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Reaction to OP's comment under Alex' answer - if this is a homework/school assignment, it's a good custom on StackOverflow to say so in the question in the first place.

If your teacher doesn't want you to use `Array.Sort`, is the assignment by any chance *primarily about* implementing a sorting algorithm? If so, it's obvious that you should implement your own and not use a library function - and again it would be best to have that in the question.

Anyway whether it's the case or not, the most sensible solution would be to create a `Person` class containing both `Name` and `Age`, sort array of people by age and fill the listbox by their names (or rather use a data binding, **[like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4278154/bind-values-from-a-list-array-to-listbox)**). Two individual arrays of related values don't make much sense in object oriented world and are harder to maintain - as is visible in your case.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to use two separate parallel arrays, the elements of each array are linked by the index. But they are only linked because you happen to put the elements in at the same index. It's not automagic. So when you move something in one array, remember the indexes used, and use those to move the same thing in the other array.

Your code moves the age in the double nested loop, so move the name in that code as well.